# How can I implement this type of search in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

assuming I have a dataframe with a lot of names like:

```
[[jack,rose,mike],
 [mike,jack,lee],
 [jeff,jack,alex]]
```

what I need is like a function that when I input "jack", the return dataframe is like:

```
[[1,0,0],
[0,1,0],
[0,1,0]]
```

Is there any method in Pandas that fits my requirement?

Comment: is your dataframe three columns? or is it one column which is a list?

Comment: I do not see any dataframes so far. All I see is a syntactically incorrect list of lists. Would you at least bother to give us a dataframe?

Comment: df.eq('jack').astype(int)

Comment: Sry, I am new to python as well as stackoverflow. Sry if I have the wrong description.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `eq`, which is short for 'equals'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['jack', 'rose', 'mike'],
                   ['mike', 'jack', 'lee'],
                   ['jeff', 'jack', 'alex']],
                  columns=['a','b','c'])

df.eq('jack') * 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exact what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare DataFrame items to a scalar:

```
(df == 'jack').astype(int)
```